# Sharding Strategies using Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm developing a new REST API using Asp.Net Core and Entity Framework Core. We will be porting over data from a legacy system that uses horizontal database partitioning (sharding). I'm trying to think of a good way to handle this in EF Core. Our previous sharding strategy involved a central Prime database, and multiple Customer databases. All queries included a `CustomerId`. We query the Prime database with the CustomerId to determine which Customer database contains the particular customer's data. The database schemas look something like this:

**Prime Database**

```
 dbo.Database  
        DatabaseId INTEGER  
        ConnectionString VARCHAR(200)  

    dbo.Customer  
        CustomerId BIGINT  
        DatabaseId INTEGER
```

**Customer Databases**

```
dbo.Order  
    CustomerId BIGINT  
    OrderId INT  
    ...
```

An example REST call for GETting an Order would be something like `http://foo.com/api/Customers/{CustomerId}/Orders/{OrderId}`

I need to have my `CustomerDbContext` use a dynamically determined Connection String with each REST request. Should I create new instances of the `DbContext` for each request? Or, can I change the connection string at run-time?

If I'm creating new DbContexts, how should I go about that? Most of the example code that I can find uses Dependency Injection from Startup.cs to create a singleton `DbContext`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've come up with. It's still very rough, and I'd really appreciate any critiques that may be offered.

I added a "UseForNewCustomer BOOLEAN" to dbo.Database. I'm using Database Migrations to create new Shards on the fly.

**ShardDbContextFactory**

```
public class ShardDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ShardDbContext>
{
    public ShardDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions opts)
    {
        return this.Create("This-Connection-String-Isn't-Used");
    }

    public ShardDbContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        var optsBldr = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ShardDbContext>();
        //This is for PostGres. If using MS Sql Server, use 'UseSqlServer()'
        optsBldr.UseNpgsql(connectionString); 
        return new ShardDbContext(optsBldr.Options);
    }
}
```

**ShardContextService.cs**

```
public interface IShardContextService {
    ShardDbContext GetContextForCustomer(int customerId);
    void ActivateShard(string connectionString, string dbType);
}

public class ShardContextService : IShardContextService {
    private readonly PrimeDbContext _primeContext;
    public ShardContextService(SystemDbContext primeContext) {
        _primeContext = primeContext;
    }

    public CustomerDbContext GetContextForCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        Database shard = null;
        var customer = _primeContext.Customers
            .Include(m=>m.Database)
            .SingleOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerId == customerId);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            shard = _primeContext.Databases.Single(db=>db.UseForNewCustomer);

            if (shard == null) throw new System.Exception("Unable to determine shard: This is a new customer, and no shards are designated as useable for new customers.");

            _primeContext.Customers.Add(new Customer {
                CustomerId = customerId,
                DatabaseId = shard.DatabaseId
            });

            _primeContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            shard = customer.Database;
        }
        return (new ShardDbContextFactory()).Create(shard.ConnectionString)
    }

    public void ActivateShard(string connectionString)
    {
        using (var customerContext = (new ShardDbContextFactory()).Create(connectionString))
        {
            customerContext.Database.Migrate();
        }

        var previous = _primeContext.Databases.SingleOrDefault(d=>d.UseForNewCustomers);
        if (previous != null)
        {
            previous.UseForNewCustomers = false;
        }

        var existing = _primeContext.Databases.SingleOrDefault(d=>d.ConnectionString == connectionString);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            existing.UseForNewCustomers = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _primeContext.Databases.Add(new Database {
                ConnectionString = connectionString,
                UseForNewCustomers = true
            });
        }
        _primeContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Controller Action for creating a new Shard**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Shard([FromBody] string connectionString) {
    try {
        _shardContextService.ActivateShard(connectionString);
        return Ok("Shard activated");
    } catch (System.Exception e) {
        return StatusCode(500, e);
    }
}
```

**Controller Action for querying**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/Customers/{customerId}/Orders/{orderId}")]
public virtual IActionResult GetOrdersForCustomer([FromRoute]long customerId, [FromRoute] long orderId)
{
    using (var ctx = _shardContextService.GetContextForCustomer(customerId))
    {
        var order = ctx.Orders.Where(o => o.CustomerId == customerId && o.OrderId = orderId).Single();
        if (order == null) return NotFound("Unable to find this order.");
        else return new ObjectResult(order);
    }
}
```